# can we copy someone else vocals and use as speak function in python?

Tags: python, pyttsx3

hey there I am wondering

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')

voices= engine.getProperty('voices') #getting details of current voice

engine.setProperty('voice', voice[0].id)
def speak(audio):

engine.say(audio) 

engine.runAndWait()
```

in this code `engine.setProperty('voice', voice[0].id)` this line set a audio for us so it is possible to use our own audio? something from a clip or something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's have a look at the documentation:

> Supported synthesizers

> Version 2.6 of pyttsx3 includes drivers for the following text-to-speech synthesizers. Only operating systems on which a driver is tested and known to work are listed. The drivers may work on other systems.

> SAPI5 on Windows XP and Windows Vista and Windows 8,8.1 , 10       NSSpeechSynthesizer on Mac OS X 10.5 (Leopard) and 10.6 (Snow Leopard)
> espeak on Ubuntu Desktop Edition 8.10 (Intrepid), 9.04 (Jaunty), and 9.10 (Karmic)

> The pyttsx3.init() documentation explains how to select a specific synthesizer by name as well as the default for each platform.

And here:

```
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
for voice in voices:
  engine.setProperty('voice', voice.id)
  engine.say('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.')
engine.runAndWait()
```

So the answer is, no, you can't use your own audio, unfortunately. Speech synthesizers are complex programs, a voice is created from many, many samples and you can't just create a new voice based on one recording.

Pyttsx3 is a framework, a python wrapper which adapts 3 already existing speech synthesizers for use in Python. What getProperty('voices') does is it gives you a list of supported voices (such as maybe Armenian or Female British English etc) for the synthesizer you have previously selected.

You can just *print* the list to get a better idea what voices are supported for your chosen engine.